# Why does Disk Utility show one "Macintosh HD" as a logical drive and another that says core storage physical volume

Tags: mac, disk-utility, core-storage

I am trying to figure out why I have 2 Macintosh HD Drives Appearing in disk utility.
One of them i can mount and shows it as being a logical drive and the second one i can't mount but it says it has no disk errors. also shows it as being a core storage physical drive, and has the same amount of gibbets as the other but has no data on it. please help

[image: HD Drive 1 Showing Master Disk]

[image: Number 2 HD Drive]

Comment: Can you show us the screen shots of Disk Utility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Edited to reflect screen shots]

Technically that is 1 Hard Drive and 4 partitions (see how they are all indented from the drive they are in).

It looks like someone [enabled showing all volume](http://www.cnet.com/news/manage-all-partitions-with-disk-utility-in-os-x/) types in your Disk utility so it's showing you things not normally shown in the GUI.

OS X has something like [LVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_volume_management) so you are seeing the Logical Volume (LV) and the CoreStorage (PV) both shown as partitions in Disk Utility. LVM provides many advantages over using a regular partition none of which are assessable in the OS X GUI, but you can read more about it on that link if you are interested. In Linux disks, logical volums, etc are labeled different from eachother but on OS X a disk can be /dev/disk0 and a LV can be /dev/disk1 which can be confusing because they are different in many ways.

Normaly you can only see the partitions that don't directly contain data by  opening Terminal.app running `diskutil list`.

So you may want to disable that setting to put the GUI back to it's simple defaults.

Comment: sorry folks kinda new to this thanks for your patience